# Why laravel validation don't displaying errors

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request, laravel-blade

I'm trying to validate a request from form and appear a problem, not showing error messages on the view.
The validation succeeds, refreshing the view but not displaying errors. Apparently $errors is always empty
I tested it on fresh installation.

Laravel Version: 5.8.33
PHP Version: 7.3.8
Database Driver & Version: mysql 5.7.22

Form is this

```
@section('content')    
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
                    <li>{{ $message }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

    <form class="form-group" method="POST" action="/trainers" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf   

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="@isset($trainer->name){{$trainer->name}}@endisset" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Slug</label>
            <input type="text" name="slug" value="@isset($trainer->slug){{$trainer->slug}}@endisset" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Descripción</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" value="@isset($trainer->description){{$trainer->description}}@endisset" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Avatar</label>
            <input type="file" name="avatar">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
        </form>
@endsection
```

The store function with validation is this

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max: 10',
            'avatar' => 'required|image',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        $trainer = new Trainer();
        $file = $request->file('avatar');

        if ($file != "") {
            $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
            }
            else{
                $name = "Sin Imagen.jpg";
                }
        // return $name; //Ver nombre archivo
        $trainer->name = $request->input('name');
        $trainer->avatar = $name;
        $trainer->description = $request->input('description');
        $trainer->slug = $request->input('slug');
        $trainer->save();

        return 'Saved';
    }
```

UPDATE
Add {{ $errors }} in blade and return [], $errors is empty

Comment: You aren't sending the validation data to the client.

Comment: What is your route for submitting?

Comment: `Route::resource('trainers', 'TrainerController');`

Comment: To add to what @Jerodev stated, you created the validation object, `$validatedData`, but you don't do anything with it. You just save the values passed in and always return 'Saved'

Comment: I'm following a tutorial that has exactly the same code as me, it works with an earlier version of Laravel

Comment: I only return 'saved' to verify that it was saved in db, when I purposely save it with errors, it reloads the view but does not show errors

Comment: @JeremíasF so you're calling it via Ajax, and the errors are returned in that request. once you redirect, you loose those errors... unless you store them in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange but solve the problem by changing local server. I used XAMPP and now I use MAMP and everything works perfect. If you are working locally with Laravel I recommend not using XAMPP.

Comment: MAMP is only for Mac, isn't it?

Comment: for Windows too

Comment: So you recommend for Laravel better to use Mac then Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$request->validate`
 edit your code and Use `$this->validate`or this code instead:

```
$messages = [
              'description.required' => 'description is required',
       ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|max: 10',
            'avatar' => 'required|image',
            'slug' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ],$messages);
```

Comment: same $this->validate

Comment: If you ever get `Class ... not found`, try fixing namespacing, so `\Validator`, or include at the top of your file with an `use Validator;` line.

Comment: use Validator; or use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `trainers` (`name`, `avatar`, `description`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Sin Imagen.jpg, ?, ?, 2019-08-28 22:49:48, 2019-08-28 22:49:48))`

Answer (score 1):

if page refresh means error object not empty...and your validation code in controller work so check html code with inspect element in browser.maybe error box is hidden or for test it you can use this code in your blade

```
  @if ($errors->any())
    @dd($errors){{-- for check error bag --}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $message)
                <li>{{ $message }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: makes no difference, inspect with chrome and i dont no see error box. Use this code in blade and add {{ $errors }} , show [], is empty?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@if(session('success_message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
              <strong>Successful!</strong> {{ session('success_message') }}</div>
            @endif
            @if(session('error_message'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
              <strong>Error!</strong> {{ session('error_message') }}</div>
            @endif

        @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <strong>Error!</strong> 
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <p>{{ $error }}</p>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
            @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

should add to method withError()
As above

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
   return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope this will help you 

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'amount' => 'required|amount|numeric|min:25'
])->validate();

if (isset($validator) && $validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->route('investment')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
}

in your blade file add below code
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class = "alert alert-danger">
  <ul>
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
     @endforeach
  </ul>
 </div>
@endif
```